# Получить число из содержимого

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt(22)
```

Ок, а если

```
parseInt('dsf')
```

Вернет NAN, ок. Хотел воспользоваться подобным условием

```
console.log(parseInt('asd') ?? 0);
```

То есть если получаем число, выводим, если нет, выводим ноль. Но вообще замечательно было бы, если  `parseInt` работал как `interval`. То есть если не число, а скажем пропись какая, просто вернуть ноль без всяких условий.

Собственно вопрос, если ли дефолтная функция которая работает по такому принципу или хотя бы сделать через условие.

Comment: Нет, на [MDN такой же совет](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)

Comment: А чем `console.log(parseInt('asd') || 0);` не устраивает?